# Origin point of Metarig acting as root bone during root motion

Tags: animation, mesh, rigging, rigify

Recently I've modelled and rigged a character using the included Human Meta-rig, and after editing out the bones I didn't need, I parented everything to a new single bone at the base of the character called root (Circled in Blue and selected)[image: Root Bone Circled in Blue]

Animating with this rig had so far worked just fine as all the actions I had made were in place, however, problems arose when I decided to animate my first root motion action. The animating process worked fine but as I imported the action into my game engine (Unreal Engine 5), the animation did not work as intended even with root motion active. It seems that the engine is reading the origin point of the Meta-rig (Called Meta-rig, circled in red below) as the root bone of the hierarchy, despite the actual root set in blender being the root bone circled before.
[image]

[image]

As I said before, when imported into UE5, the root of the skeleton seems to be that origin point.[image]

Am I missing something? I have tried reparenting the root bone to be the first in the hierarchy and making it so that it replaces the "Metarig" in the object list to no avail, since it seems to not be possible. Am I doing something wrong? Should that tiny orange dot be moving at all or even considered a bone? Any help or insight is very appreciated.

Many thanks.

Comment: No one knows? Im truly at a loss here, my bone hierarchy in UE4 is considering that Metarig as the first bone of the chain and i have no idea how to get rid of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to figure this out myself after all.

The problem is that UE5, for some dumb reason, takes the name of the armature object and makes it the first bone of the hierarchy if that object is not named "armature" in blender, hence why it was creating the "Metarig" bone at the beginning of my hierarchy. I only had to change the name to that and the root was correctly recognized.

Of course, that means that all my in place animations with the previous skeleton are now broken and I basically have to redo a lot of work I've already done. The joys of game dev, huh? At least I fixed the problem.

Thanks for nuthin bozos. jk I hope this helps someone at some point.

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, the root movement animation still won't work. The solution to this is to create keys for the skeleton itself and move the animation keys of the root bone there. But that's not all, you need to set the rotation -quaternions on the stage and swap the keys of the Y and Z axes with the positions of the movement and rotation. And the y-axis is reflected in -.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).